# Frameset: Deprecated Frameset is not working

Tags: html, frameset-iframe

]I am trying to convert frameset code into iframe as it is known that frameset is deprecated. But I am stuck on how to replace those attributes in an iframe which used in the frameset. please point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

```html
//frameset Current code 

<frameset id="AnlagenFrame" rows="0,*" frameborder="NO" border="0" framespacing="0">
  <frame src="example.html" name="bus" scrolling="no" noresize marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" title="_vcbus" >
  <frame src="example.html" name="lage" scrolling="no" noresize marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" title="_anlage">
 </frameset>
  
  
  //iframe code which i am working 
  
   <iframe id="Frame" rows="0,*" style="border: none;" framespacing="0">
  <frame src="example.html" name="bus" scrolling="no" noresize marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" title="_vcbus" >
  <frame src="example.html" name="lage" scrolling="no" noresize marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" title="_anlage">
 </iframe>
```

Comment: Which attributes? Frames and iframes are not interchangeable.

Comment: @Quentin : thanks for your response, frameborder, framespacing, scrolling, rows which has been used in code ...in place what should I use in iframe

Comment: What would you expect to use instead of framespacing and rows when there isn't space between iframes to describe and when iframes aren't organised into rows?!

Comment: @Quentin: Actually, I have to error-free this code but when I am validating the code following errors has been displaying

Comment: @Quentin: Any idea of how to error-free this code

Comment: The first row in each frame has a height of 0, so I've no idea what the point of it is. Just link directly to the URL you put in the second frame. Forget about the frame one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209434/discussion-between-asiya-fatima-and-quentin).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly You'll have to create `iframes` for each `frame` you have.But then most attributes of iframes are also depreciated with HTML5, best option is to write custom css for it.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: yeah I have updated my code.now can you point me in the right direction to error free the code

Comment: Someone, please give suggestions on how should I code properly